# Admin service in microservices paradigm

Tags: design-patterns, pagination, architecture, microservices, aggregation

So to be shorter my problem sounds like this:

I'm trying to design microservices so I have multiple domains like (users, items, sales, surveys, comments etc.). Each microservice has its own database. Now I'm trying to design admin-service which must have logic of admin groups, different view rules and so on. But the first problem is that application must have pagination and filtering on each column. Hence I need representation of all my different databases in one place like real time DWH. And this looks awkward.

Do you have any other best practices how to solve this problem or maybe it's normal to keep real-time DWH

P.S. All my databases are postgres dbs. App on Spring web

Comment: TBH it is not very clear why your app needs to have "real time DWH" due to pagination requirement can you please elaborate.

Comment: @GuruStron Hi. My application faced with filtering and pagination problem in microservices. So we have multiple independent microservices and now we want to add admin service, which must be able view all data from all microservices in table view. For example table with colums brand and brand owner. So we have brand microservice and user microservice, and we must implement pagination with filtering on brand name and owner's name, surname, lastname. And there are more cases like this (about 50 tables). How can I achive that normally? Real time dwn is one of my assumption and not a need

Comment: @GuruStron I also have read this post  https://rafaborrego.co.uk/how-to-do-pagination-across-domains-in-microservices-architectures/, but in case with admin service it seems like I need duplicate all tables in my admin service, or user's data to be duplicated on brands micoreservice like in onther place where i need user data. But this sounds weird coz all my microservices will hold much more data then they really need just to maintain admin functionality